# Find if a Long ( in a list ) can fit in a List of Long values

Tags: java, collections, time-complexity

I've a `List<Long>` (A) indicating the free sizes available for different partitions.
Users come to ask with a `List<Long>` ( B) indicating the file sizes they want to store.

Now if any Long (from B) can fit into any free size in A, we want to re-use the partition, otherwise create new partition for them.

How can I know if any of the `Long` value from B have value less than any of the `Long` in A.

If I use iterative approach to scan through A and find out if any of B will fit, it will cause O(n^2) runtime, but can we do better ?

Any Data structure exists for this kind of problem ?

Comment: If you keep A sorted, you can check the top in constant time or find the smallest available partition with a binary search.

Comment: Keeping it sorted if add more burden at the time of storing. And even if we use binary search, it may not be efficient. For instance the free sizes could be 1G, 2G, 3GB, and user comes to ask for a 100 MB file. Then we will want to use the free slot of 1G instead of 2G.

Comment: Storing would cost roughly the same as searching. And a binary search will allow you to find the smallest available slot, like I said.

Comment: Store it in a `SortedSet` such as `TreeSet` - it has some nice methods for finding things like the smallest element greater than a particular argument, and such like.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem : I thought about Set's but they do not allow duplicates, so they are not good for my case.

Comment: Of course they're OK.  Just have a class that stores an id for the partition as well as the size of it, and store that.  Use a Comparator that sorts them by size.

Comment: You could store a collection of values, or google guava has some exotic collections like SortedSetMultiMap...

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem The comparator would have to sort by ID also. And you would need to construct a psuedo-partition for lookups.

Comment: Yes, I ended up creating a array of my custom class. The custom class will have ID and size. Then do a Arrays.sort with custom comparator, and then do a binary search by the size.

Comment: @shmosel yes, you're right.  OK, maybe my suggestion wasn't the best one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an O(n) solution:

Given:

```
List<Long> A; // size n
List<Long> B; // size m
```

Find the 2 edges:

```
long a = Collections.max(A);  // O(n)
long b = Collections.min(B);  // O(m)
```

Then see if the largest A can fit the smallest B:

```
boolean canFit = a >= b; // O(1)
```

Overall time complexity O(n + m) which for n approx equal to m is O(n).

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. However this does give canFit in a very efficient manner, however since i need to know the partition also.

Comment: @NoviceUser you didn't say you need to know which exact one fits: *How can I know if any of the Long value from B have value less than any of the Long in A.*.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the `NavigableSet` interface. Store in such a set the available partitions with a sort key of size. Then use the `ceiling` operator to find the smallest partition at least as large as the desired one.  `NavigableSet` also supports `add` and `remove` operations, which is all you need to maintain the partition list dynamically.

Sensible implementations of `NavigableSet` like `TreeSet` provide O(log n) performance for all three operations, where n is the number of available partitions.  When you allocate one, you'll want to remove it and re-insert the remaining sliver with a smaller key.

Another approach is to use an an array of logarithmically-sized buckets.  This is what `malloc`-like memory allocators tend to do. They will not match size requests to available blocks as accurately as the approach above, but they'll be very close to constant time.  See the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44213973/how-does-dlmalloc-coalesce-chunks/44357497#44357497) for an example with details.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I ended up using `TreeSet` using my custom comparator. Works like a charm !

Comment: @NoviceUser Interesting. Use my suggestion and accept another answer?  Not important. Just strange.